# Sum of two columns as criteria

Tags: sql, surface

I am trying to match product entries by their surface.

My thought was that the below query should be valid.

But it doesn't work, I am receiving:

> Unknown column 'surface' in 'where clause'

```
SELECT SUM(width*height) AS surface FROM products WHERE surface>50
```

Comment: I have no idea what sqli is, but I assume you meant MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

The function sum is not for this use case. With sum you get the sum of all rows. What you are looking for is.

```
SELECT (width*height) AS surface FROM products WHERE surface>50
```

Comment: Couldn’t test it. But if it is not working try replacing “surface” with “(height * width)”

Comment: Thanks,

Underneath works now:

SELECT * FROM products WHERE (ArtWidth*ArtHeight)>50

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
 SELECT * FROM products WHERE (width*height)>50
```